# Как сгенерировать массив с буквами без повторов?

Tags: javascript, массивы, set

Мне надо сгенерировать масив с 5 неповторяющихся букв.

```js
let characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
let charactersLength = characters.length;

function generateArray(length) {

     let result = [];
     for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          result.push(characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() *
               charactersLength)));
     }
     return result;
}

let generatedArray = generateArray(5);
let uniqueArray = [...new Set(generatedArray)];


console.log(generatedArray);
console.log(uniqueArray);
```

`uniqueArray` просто удалаляет повторную букву, как мне сделать проверку перед тем как визивать функцию?

Comment: Надо 1) убирать уже взятую букву из набора 2) декрементировать верхнюю границу генерируемого номера буквы в массиве.

Comment: что за буква в наборе? @Akina

Comment: `let characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function generateArray(length) {
  const uniqueSet = new Set();
  while (uniqueSet.size < length) {
    const candidate = 97 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 26);
    uniqueSet.add(candidate);
  }
  return [...uniqueSet].map((x) => String.fromCharCode(x));
}

console.log(generateArray(5).join(","));
console.log(generateArray(5).join(","));
console.log(generateArray(5).join(","));
console.log(generateArray(5).join(","));
```

Comment: можете обьяснить что в return?

Comment: Три точки это spread оператор. В комбинации с квадртными скобками он конвертирует Set в обычный масив. Далее я использую map для перебора всех элементов масива и преобразования кодов символов в символы. Можно обойтись и без преобразования, сделать также как вы сделали в вопросе с вытаскиваем символа из строки. Мой вариант мне показался просто интересным.